# Call to WMS occsionally doesn't return a map

Tags: python, gis

I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot an issue with some WMS calls I'm making to the ESA's Corine Landcover service.

The following returns a map:

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService

wms = WebMapService('https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS',
            version='1.1.1')

img = wms.getmap(layers=['12'],
            srs='EPSG:4326',
            size=(600, 500),
            bbox=(-2.30712890625, 51.3992056535538, -0.54931640625, 53.1731192026406),
            format='image/tiff')

out = open('/data/tests/corine_test_map_geotiff.tif', 'wb')
out.write(img.read())
out.close()
```

The following code runs without error and saves a .tif file to disk, but the file is blank (literally a white image):

```
from owslib.wms import WebMapService

wms = WebMapService('https://copernicus.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/services/Corine/CLC2018_WM/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS',
            version='1.1.1')

img = wms.getmap(layers=['12'],
            srs='EPSG:4326',
            size=(600, 500),
            bbox=(1.25960826873779, 52.1964546608317, 1.2764310836792, 52.2050819340913),
            format='image/tiff')

out = open('/data/tests/corine_test_map_geotiff.tif', 'wb')
out.write(img.read())
out.close()
```

There are no differences between the two bounding boxes except their extents. Both extents cover areas somewhere over the UK and are therefore within the bounds of the Corine WMS data. The only thing I can think of is that the second call's bounding box is considerably smaller than the first call. Does anyone know if there's a minimum bounding box size which you can send to the Corine WMS service?

Or perhaps the image size parameter in the call is too large for the size of the bounding box?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try adding `EXCEPTIONS='application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage'` to your getmap request to see if you get an error message.

Comment: After some further investigation, I think the issue is an interaction between the bounding box extent and the dimensions of the size parameter in the `getmap` call. You can't return a 500x500px .tif if your area extent only covers a few kilometers on a side, for example. I think the challenge now is to work out how to programatically adjust the size parameter given the bbox. Migfht be better suited to a new question, however.